# Unable to recieve sensor data to Watson cloud using Edge SDK 1.0

Tags: sdk, analytics

I am using EDGE SDK 1.0 ,created a gateway device simulator code in java. In my program, after connecting to gateway into cloud. i am sending data of sensor device which is already registered in cloud . given below is the code snippet

```
public class SampleApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties props = loadProperties();
    String ORG_ID = props.getProperty("Organization-ID");
    String AUTH_KEY = props.getProperty("API-Key");
    String AUTH_TOKEN = props.getProperty("API-Token");
    String APP_ID = props.getProperty("Application-ID");
    String GATEWAY_ID = props.getProperty("Gateway-ID");
    String GATEWAY_TYPE = props.getProperty("Gateway-Type");
    String GATEWAY_AUTH_TOKEN = props.getProperty("Authentication-Token");

    EdgeProperties edgeProps = new EdgeProperties(ORG_ID, APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, 
 AUTH_TOKEN,GATEWAY_TYPE, GATEWAY_ID, GATEWAY_AUTH_TOKEN);

    EdgeAnalyticsClient edgeAnalyticsClient = new EdgeAnalyticsClient(edgeProps);
    EdgeAnalyticsAgent eaa = edgeAnalyticsClient.getAgent();

    // Start edge analytics agent with the new gateway.
    eaa.start();

    // (Optional) Register an alert handler
    eaa.registerDeviceActionHandler(new AlertFileActionHandler("ABC.CSV"));

    // Publish a event every 10 seconds.
      int i = 0;
      Random random = new Random();
      while (i++ < 100000) {
        JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
        data.addProperty("pir", random.nextInt(2));
        data.addProperty("temp", 34 + random.nextDouble() - random.nextInt(3));
        System.out.println(" data is "+data.toString());
      Event event = new Event("84_18_26_00_00_07_AB_55", "Sensor", data.toString());
      eaa.deviceData(event);
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
  }

  private static Properties loadProperties() throws IOException {
    String configPath = "sample-config/sample_app.conf";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream(configPath));
    return props;
  }

  }
```

But above code is not sending data to right topic, or it is not showing data onto my internetofthings service created in watson cloud. I have used sample programs provided by IBM, those sample programs are working fine. But when i am created my program using same pom.xml , it is not publishing data.

Pom.xml is 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.vriot</groupId>
<artifactId>IBMConnector_V1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>IBMConnector_V1</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>

    <!-- This project specific properties -->
    <maven.javadoc.failOnError>false</maven.javadoc.failOnError>
    <maven.build.skipTests>true</maven.build.skipTests>

    <!-- General properties -->
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>

    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin configuration -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edge-sdk-1.0.0</groupId>
        <artifactId>edge-sdk-1.0.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\lib\edge-sdk-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.messaging</groupId>
        <artifactId>watson-iot</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bidib.jbidib.org.qbang.rxtx</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxtxcomm</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I know java but not Watson IoT things. Compare 1-2 lines before `edgeApp.eaa.start()` with sample apps. They should be of similar logic. Possibly your code needs something before `edgeApp.eaa.start()` to introduce `ABC.CSV`. Without knowing their sample apps, actually it is difficult to confirm.

As none answered here so far, you can ask on [IBM developer works](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/ask.html?topics=watson).